# Cross fading Image views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi i have a doubt in crossfading imageviews

1) In my project i have two images the first images has alpha =1 and oncllick = myDhoni1 and the second images has alpha = 0 so the first image only visible initially when i run the application in emulator.

Now i have a doubt here if i click the first image it fade out and the second image fade in and again if i click the second image fadeout and first image fade in but here i have only specified onClick function to only the first image so if i click the second image the code should not work bcz i didn't specify the onClick funtion to the second image but the code is working fine which creates the doubt and

2) I want to how the crossfading works?

code:

```
package com.example.aravi.demo_0501;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void myDhoni1(View dhoni){
    ImageView a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if(b.getAlpha()==0f){
        b.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2500);
        a.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2500);
    }else{
        b.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2500);
        a.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2500);
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image is 
 pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:onClick="myDhoni1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/dhoni1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/dhoni" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you also post the code of your layout?

Comment: HI sandesh . i have added the layout code. can u check it up plz?

Answer (score 0):

Here, Crossfade is happening for the `alpha` property of the `imageview`s, once you click the image and make the 2nd `imageview` appear, The first image `alpha` becomes 0, This doesn't mean the image has disappeared from the place. View is still there but  fully transparent. So click events on the 1st image **still apply**.

You can do this workaround in your case:
In the method myDhoni1, after referring to the imageviews, add this line:

```
ImageView a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

if(a.getAlpha()==0f)
     return;
```

What we did is, once the first image becomes transparent, we no make the click listener execute